# How can i dismiss view controller if internet connected

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

i am trying to dismiss view controller if internet connected. When there is no internet it present my noInternetViewController but when i reconnect to internet, noInternetViewController view didnt dismissed.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachability)
}

func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.isReachable {
        if noInternet == true {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.noInternet = false
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    } else {
        noInternet = true
        if noInternet == true {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let noInternetViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NoInternetViewController") as! NoInternetViewController
                noInternetViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
                self.present(noInternetViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And NoInternetViewController:

```
import UIKit

class NoInternetViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: I recognized when noInternetViewController presented and after i reconnect, reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification) func not triggered. I think it is because of removeObserver but i couldnt find correct way to use it.

Comment: `noInternet = true; if noInternet == true {` If you set it to true in the line above it will always be true. BTW to add == true is redundant

Comment: You are using `self.dismissViewController`,  but you need to dismiss the noInternetComtroller; you could keep a reference to the presented comtroller in a property rather than the boolean

Comment: I think a better approach would be to have an empty rootViewController and have a singleton that keeps track of the reachability changes. When reachability changes, the singleton should change the view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `NoInternetViewController`, you can add a `Observer` to it as well. When you received connection, post a notification to trigger it's selector to dismiss itself.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receivedConnection), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "ReceivedConnection"), object: nil)
}

func receivedConnection() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```